# SMS запрос: способ запроса через обычный номер

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, на многих сайтах встречал такое:

> Для активации отправьте SMS на номер +79##875#### со следующим текстом: *****

Вопрос, как реализовать данное действие. На данный момент знаком только с смс-биллингами, с короткими номерами, а тут обычный мобильный номер. Причем стоимость определяется как обычное смс для вашего оператора.

Спасибо!

Comment: А вы уверены насчет стоимости ? :)

Comment: @shurik да, вполне. Проверил. Данное сиё повстречал при активации хостинга.

Comment: ну используют сервис отправки и приема смс, недорого 0,2р за смс отправленное и 0.0р за принятое, я на сайте инет магазина использую это.

Comment: @shurik так как это реализовать? можно поподробнее :)

Comment: А хз, это не я использовал.

зы: я только с короткими номерами по партнерке с мобильным оператором работал)

Comment: Это тоже самое что и короткий номер, только за короткий вы переплачиваете.

Comment: Грубо говоря, в сервер втыкается модем. Ну а далее - пишем ПО, которое будет обрабатывать приходящие смс-ки. Чтобы кто-то предлагал такого рода услуги - не встречал. Но вполне можно воспользоваться и коротким номером, ибо минимальная стоимость смс всего 30 копеек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть сервисы, позволяющие это сделать, например SmsPilot: http://smspilot.ru/sms_inter.php

Сервисный номер +79021121075 тарифицируется как обычная смс, в начале сообщения указывается префикс, тот что был получен при регистрации аккаунта в этом сервисе.

Если без ответа, то сообщение оплачивается по 29 копеек за входящее, если с ответом, то 29 копеек + стоимость ответной смс.

Answer (score 0):

Ну развели там в комментах

Короче тема тут такая смотрю денег у тебя много, так воспользуйся услугами готового сервиса.

Стоимость отправки смс от 0,6 до 0,25к за смс в зависимости от внесенной суммы оплаты.

API по отправке есть. так же можешь указать от кого это смс.

Можешь заказать короткий номер на который ты сможешь принимать смс от юзверей.

Только мой тебе совет, мало кто возьмет и отправит смс на какой-то номер.

А вот если ты сам отправишь юзверю смс и скажешь ввести код на сайте чтобы отписаться от смс ибо получить доп инфу тогда да. Но обязательно на сайте крупными буквами напиши что если вы вводите код из смс с Вас не будет списано 500рублей как на многих палевных ресурсах, типа выиграйте Iphone отправив смс на номер, и внизу мааааленькими буквами про подписку которая стоит 300р каждый месяц.

Я к чему про сервис говорю - т.к. это выгоднее чем покупать симку и оборудование. Ты знаешь тарифы при которых отправка смс в сутки более 500штук будет стоить 25копеек за смс? я нет!